# Smart/dumb components hierarchy

Tags: angular

In a smart/dumb components pattern, is there any instance where smart component would:

1. not have its route? (basically, correspond to a concept of a `page`)
2. would be a child of a dumb component?

I am trying to see potential cases where smart component might be somewhere deeper inside component tree and I can think of any scenario other than if `page` level smart component gets too many unrelated data from the app state.

In that case I see a use case of smart componeny being a child of some dumb component deep down the tree.

But I am not sure if there are any drawbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are thinking about `react.js` not `angular.js`, there is no need to maintain the state in root component/page. Angular has the advantage here because we have multiple ways of sharing state.

- **Services** - we can have a singleton service, to share data between any kind of components, so no need for state management and cascading `@Input` or `@Output`
- **Subject(event bus)** - we can use the subject/behaviour subject to call events over any component.
- **ngRx** - Taken from the react state management, where we maintain a common state and this state can be used to share data between components.

React overcame this error, of maintaining the state at the root level, by using a store(redux) to enable better state management, which eliminates this problem.

So do not worry about the `smart/dumb component pattern` because Angular has a different design architecture/implementation methods compared to react, so we should take both of them as `apples and oranges`!

**This answer is opinion based, this is my viewpoint, I hope this helps you and I am not making any statements, this is my knowledge level, I'm sure there is more to this question!**

Comment: thanks for your answer! just to notice, injecting any service into compoment makes it smart. so, you are implying that its fine to have smart component as a child of a dumb one?

Comment: @tlzg yes, we have more flexibility to make dumb components smart at any level in angular

Answer (score 0):

I also like the smart/damp component concept. I am using it in my projects and I didn't have any problems with this.

Regarding the first question: `not have its route? (basically, correspond to a concept of a page)` Yes it can be if you have for example modal windows where you have a complex UI and you want to separate them into small pieces

Regarding the second question: `Would be a child of a dumb component?` My opinion regarding this is - `NO`, if you have the case when the child component is smart, then the parent damp is not damp anymore :).

Mainly as a damp component, you will use the small components where you have a list, grid, or any easy logic that you can separate into a component and add an OnPush to that. And I don't think there will be a case where you will have a Smart component as a child.